# Is it okay to use multiple package managers?

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

With Ubuntu (or other versions of linux) is it problematic to use different package managers at the same time?  As in, will it cause me grief if I install some programs using apt-get and others using synaptic?

I've been doing this for years without incident, but I'd appreciate some reassurance from someone more knowledgeable than myself.

Comment: Doesn't Synaptic use apt-get?

Comment: Ah... so what you're both saying is that Ubuntu Software Center and Synaptic are basically graphical front-ends for apt-get? I didn't realize this.

Comment: ... Yes, and apt-get is a front-end to dpkg.

Comment: Ok, cool. That's the info I was looking for. If one of you writes that into an answer, I'll accept it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is **Synaptic** and **Ubuntu Software Center** use the same underlying commands as `apt-get` and `dpkg` to do the actual management and installation. One test is to install a program using one method (say apt-get) and verify that it shows up in Sofware Center and Synaptic database as installed.

In other words, **Synaptic** and **Ubuntu Software Center** are graphical front ends for the relevant command line tools.

Using any of these should be fine.

See [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1684446) for a similar discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the graphical tools available on Ubuntu are just front ends for apt (muon, synaptic, aptitude, Ubuntu Software Center,... fall in this category). With those, you will never get problems. However, they cannot run at the same time, because they lock the local apt files - meaning that for example you have to close aptitude in order to run synaptic.

However, it's not impossible to install a completely different package manager like rpm or portage. If more than one package manager is installed, you probably will run into problems if you don't take special precautions, because they don't know about files installed by each other and might overwrite or delete them.